# How to control formatting of numbers with decimal points?

Tags: format, number

What's happening now : if the values are getting displayed as eg: 100 and no decimal value then it is displayed as '100' and if Decimal value is '.70', it is displayed as ' 100.7'.

What we want : If the values are getting displayed as eg: 100 and no decimal value then it should be displayed as '100.00' and if Decimal value is '.70', it should display as ' 100.70'.

Variable : ${!Case.Current_Payment_Amount__c}

Answer (score 2):

If this variable is on Visualforce Page, then you can format it with `apex:outputText`

```
<apex:outputText value="{0, number, 0.00}">
    <apex:param value="{!Case.Current_Payment_Amount__c}" />
</apex:outputText>
```

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_outputText.htm